# Is it possible to optimize Zencoder video thumbnails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, video, encoding, thumbnails

I'm working on a Rails3 project with video encoding through Zencoder, assets are stored on Amazon S3.

```
...
:thumbnails => {
  :number => 5,
  :size => "620x465",
  :base_url => "s3://my_bucket/path/to/asset/thumbnails/"
}
...
```

I'm creating 5 thumbnails for each video encoded, and each PNG (same ratio as the video: 620x465) weight about 600 Ko.

Is it possible to preserve ratio but optimize the weight?

I can set the format to JPG but I can't see any other option in Zencoder API: https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/encoding/thumbnails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Zencoder support answer:

> This is something that we're hoping to add in the future, though I don't know of a definite timeline right now. Keep an eye on our blog and newsletter and we'll announce it when the option is available.

I hope they will soon :-)